# Passing List<Object> from one activity to another

Tags: android

I have a List in one of my activity. I need to pass it to another activity and use the elements in it.

ActivityOne.java

```
newsListy.add(new News(title, description, thumbnail);
      Intent newsIntent = new Intent(getActivity(),Second.class);
                    newsIntent.putExtra("NewsItems", newsListy);
startActivity(newsIntent);
```

Second.class

```
data =  in.getSerializableExtra("NewsItems");
```

Also, retrive value from the list and assign it to a String title, description and thumbnail

Comment: Its been answered a dozen times. 
 [This][1] one, for example


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android

Comment: @Arnab. I know how to pass single data. I wanted to know about passing a List<Object>

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass a custom object between activities, like for instance a List of a custom object :

> List<'CustomObject'>

Your custom object class have to implement [Parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html).

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that your Object implements Serializable interface or else you will get some kind of parse exception. But as @Alex mentioned  also declare your `List`'s generic type with your Object like : `List<'CustomObject'>`

Implementing `Parcelable` is the best way to do it, but it requires more effort.